# An impossible congruence

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Using a computer, I was able to observe that for an integer $n\neq 0$ divisible by $4$, the congruences
$$xy^2+y^2+y-x\equiv0\equiv x-xy-y-\frac n2\mod n\tag{*}$$
are not solvable. Hence the following:

**Conjecture.** Let $n\neq 0$ be a multiple of $4$. Then there exist no integers $x$ and $y$ for which (*) holds.

The next observation may come in handy:

**Lemma.** If $n$ is a multiple of $4$ and $x,y$ satisfy (*), then $x$ and $y$ are even.

*Proof.* Assume first that $y$ is odd. Write $n=4k$. Then $x-xy-y-2k\equiv 0\mod n$ implies $x(1-y)\equiv 2k+y\mod n$, where the left-hand side is even, and the right-hand side is odd, a contradiction. Hence $y$ is even. From $x\equiv xy+y+\frac n2\mod n$ we deduce that also $x$ must be even.$_\blacksquare$

How can the conjecture be proven?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should settle it:

Multiplying $x-xy-y-\frac n2\equiv 0\mod n$ by $y$ and using that $y\frac n2\equiv 0\mod n$ since $y$ is even, we get
$$xy-xy^2-y^2\equiv 0\mod n.$$

Adding this to the congruence $xy^2+y^2+y-x\equiv 0\mod n$ gives
$xy+y-x\equiv 0\mod n$, that is
$$x\equiv xy+y\mod n.$$

Replacing the first $x$ in $x-xy-y-\frac n2\equiv 0\mod n$ by $xy+y$ gives
$$-\frac n2\equiv 0\mod n,$$
a contradiction.

Comment: Note however the solution $n=0,x=-2,y=2.$

Comment: I added an answer showing how to view your proof as arising by *elimination* of $\,x\,$ (a method that applies very generally). @Anne Usually modulus $n=0$ is excluded in ENT problems.

Answer (score 2):

*Conceptually* $ $ your proof is *discoverable* by **eliminating** $\,\color{#c00}x\,$ as below

$$\begin{align}
a\:\!=&\ \  (\color{#0a0}{y^2-1})\,\color{#c00}x + y(1+y)\\[.2em]
b\:\!=&\  \ \ \,  (\color{#0a0}{1-y})\,\color{#c00} x -y-n/2\\[.4em]
\hline
\Rightarrow\ \ \color{#90f}a+(\color{#0a0}{1+y})\color{#90f}b\, =&\ \,  {-}(1+y)n/2
\end{align}$$

Therefore, $ $ we may conclude that: $\ n\mid \color{#90f}{a,b}\,\Rightarrow\, n\mid (1+y)n/2\!\underset{{\rm cancel}\ n/2}\Longrightarrow 2\mid 1+y,\,$ contra $\,y\,$ even.